# Going back to previous view is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

Storyboard:

[Navigation Controller] -> [ViewController1] -> [ViewController2]

Both ViewController1 and ViewController2 have Tables Views in them with TableViewCell.

I have control-dragged from TableViewCell of ViewController1 to ViewController2.

ViewController1.swift has following function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showview2", sender:self)
}
```

When application runs, i can click on row on ViewController1 and ViewController2 shows up. It has a Back button at the top left. BUT, it does not work, nothing happens when i click Back button.

Comment: Why control-dragged from `tableViewCell`? Just create a `segue` from viewController1 to viewController2.

Comment: If you stop in the debugger somewhere in your ViewController2 code you can inspect the navigation stack, with `po self.navigationController?.viewControllers`.  Is ViewController1 the previous view controller in the stack?

Comment: sasquatch> As far as i can tell it does not get dragged unless you start from tableviewcell

Comment: Aaron Golden> i see the following: po self.navigationController?.viewControllers     
Optional([<myapp.ViewController1: 0x7fe3dbd3r891>, <myapp.ViewController2: 0x7fe3dbc20116>])

Comment: Can you show the back button code here? what are you using `push` or `model` to present your second controller ?

Comment: It's fine to wire up the show segue from the table view cell. In this case, the show segue will automatically fire when the table view cell is selected, and you should not call `performSegueWithIdentifier` explicitly.

Comment: Finally got this working... i had a something called a 'Bar Button Item' (Back) appearing on the ViewController2 - i have no idea how it got there (or what it. meant)- when i deleted it from View, things started working. Now i see <FirstViewControllerTitle appear on ViewController2 - and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Ctrl+Drag from TableViewCell you should do it from ViewController. I tried to reproduce the problem from your description.

What I found is ViewController2 gets pushed twice once from the Storyboard and second time because of `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showview2", sender:self)`

My suggestion:
Instead of adding from TableViewCell do it from ViewController.
You can add it by Ctrl+drag from `ViewController` to `ViewController2`

[image]

See the image below
[image]

Hope this works!

Comment: Setting up the segue worked, but that did not resolve the issue. The actual problem seemed to be something else - please see my last comment. Your inputs much appreciated.